# Read data from csv file in Highchart Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, linechart

I want to read data from CSV file which is located into assets folder in my local system. And in CSV file there are 5,6 column in it.

**Note:** Angular Project, So there is no jquery.

Comment: @KacperMadej, Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Fronend applicaions can't reach your local system. This is security issue. File Upload input is created for this which is one way input . So  If u want to read file from local system then you need to do it in Api not in angular. If u want to do it in angular, take csv file into your project folder or take with file input

Comment: @pc_coder, ok got your point, one more thing I need to know that is how I define which column of csv file is shown in x-axis and y-axis. for e.g: I want to show column 2 of csv in x-axis and column 3 in y-axis.

Comment: I added one answer. There there is an example file input . You can return your csv fie into  json object and with this object you can reach any data you want

Comment: @pc_coder, I am not using input field in my case, I am using highchart API to read csv file for example: 
`data: {
csvURL: 'assests/filename.csv'
}`

Now I am stuck at this point, how to define which column of csv file is show in x-axis and which column show in y-axis

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/livedata-csv did u check this?

Comment: If your code in asset s like that then your url type is correct. Did u integrate related library for this?

Comment: I edited answer check if you iimported this library?

Comment: @pc_coder, Yes I am using related libraries in project as you mentioned in your answer, but the problem is that, I am confuse how to define which column should use in x-axis and which column should use in y-axis, because in my csv file there are 5 columns in it. and I need to show column 3 in x-axis and column 5 in y-axis of my csv file

Comment: Cant do it with that for this angular api u should read csv convert object and write your x and y xis with this object

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel

Answer (score 0):

Reference to comments - you should be able to define your data from CSV by using the **seriesMapping**, **parsed** or **complete** feature.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parsed

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete

Please check the demo, test it and try to implement it to your needs. If this wouldn't help reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor which I could work on.

Comment: Can you please show code sample because API documentation not much explanatory

Comment: Could you prepare an example how your data looks like how it is done in the demos under API links?

Comment: Here is the demo code with **sample_data.csv** file
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-violet-h7xvv?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: In my case there are two line chart
**In first line chart:** I need to show **column name: Date** in x-axis and **column name: Amount** in y-axis.
**In second line chart:**  I need to show **column name: Date** in x-axis and **column name: ID** in y-axis.

Column Names define in sample_data.csv file.

Comment: @MueedUllah Your CSV parsed via using the `complete` callback: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v3j2yL6z/, however it will be much easier to change the CSV data, but I assumed that you can't do it.